# jquery ui in a dynamic environment

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am dynamically adding elements to a page using jquery.  The elements I am adding are coming from a database, and each retrieved object should be wrapped in a ui accordion.

The accordion is working fine for elements on the page which have NOT been added dynamically, however all subsequently added accordions do not seem to be functioning as accordions.

QUESTION:

How do I ensure all dynamically added accordions are assigned the accordion behaviour??

Any help appreciated guys...

EDIT:

// jquery in the document.ready function:

```
$('#accordion').accordion();
```

// php which dynamically adds objects wrapped in accordions to the page:

```
// -=> Container for activities:
echo'
<div id="con_activities_'.$project_id.'" class="float" style="width: 100%; height: auto; background-color: transparent; ">    

<div id="accordion">
';

while(  $activities_array = mysql_fetch_array( $activities )  ){
$activity_id             = $activities_array['id'];
$activity_parent_id      = $activities_array['parent_id'];
$activity_created        = $activities_array['created'];
$activity_title          = $activities_array['title'];
$activity_desc           = $activities_array['desc'];

echo'
<h3><a href="#">'.$activity_title.'</a></h3>
<div>'.$activity_desc.'</div>
';
}

// -=> Close container for activities:
echo'
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
';
```

Comment: You need to initialize them ( .accorion() ). If you include some code we can show you were a good place to "turn them on" would be. Unless what you mean is that you are adding additional panels to an existing accordion, in which case you probably need to add the content in a different way then you are currently doing.

Comment: Maybe include the output html since that code will work just fine, assuming you've got your php in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the fact that you never closed the accordion (so the output isn't quite what you expected) that code will work just fine. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gYCt5/6/)